# ActiveMQ distributed transaction + scaling

Tags: java, spring, transactions, activemq-classic

I'm currently using Oracle AQ and would like to replace it by a persisted ActiveMQ.

**My current setup using Oracle AQ is:**

- DB server: Oracle DB with a queue Q1
- App server 1: Has a producer and multiple listeners on Q1
- App server 2: Has a producer and multiple listeners on Q1

**The following flow is currently followed:**

App server 1:

- Incoming message via a webservice
- Start DB transaction
- Save message in DB with id
- Post id and other information of the message on queue Q1
- commit transaction

App server 2:

- Same setup, horizontal scaled

**Requirements**

When implementing ActiveMQ I want the data to the DB and the post on the queue in the same transaction. So that if one does a rollback, the other will do it as well.

Because I need to be able to produce messages on the queue with both app-servers at the same time, I need to run the ActiveMQ broker on the DB-server, and not on the app-servers. Otherwise they will act as a 'master slave'.

I an [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2009/jw-01-spring-transactions.html?page=1) I read, they explain how you can share transaction resources.
But this is done assuming you put the ActiveMQ broker on the same server as where the transaction is started.
Is there any way, except using JTA to accomplish this?

**I'm using Java with:**

- Spring 2.5.6
- Hibernate 3.3
- TransactionManager: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager
- DataSource: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this. But isn't this what you're looking for?

```
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.JmsException;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

    @Autowired
    private Queue someQueue;

    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private SomeRepository repository;

    public SomeServiceImpl() {}

    public SomeServiceImpl(ConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory, SomeRepository repository) {
        this.jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(activeMQConnectionFactory);
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = {JmsException.class, RepositoryException.class})
    public void sendMessage(final SomeObject object) {
        repository.save(object);
        jmsTemplate.send(       
        new MessageCreator() {          
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createObjectMessage(object.getSpecialId());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This way if there is a failure while saving the object or an issue with sending the message to the queue (JMSException), the local transaction will be rolled back and the object won't be persisted. I don't think you will be needing a distributed transaction.